# Remove common values from multidimension array perl

Tags: perl

I want remove common element from array. For example:

```
array1 =
[
{'id'=>78597,'data'=>'great'}
 ];

array2=
[
{'id'=>78345,'data'=>'first'},{'id'=>78597,'data'=>'great'},
{'id'=>78355,'data'=>'second'}
]
```

Now key Id `'78597'` is common in both array
Now i to want remove that element from array2 based on the key `'id'`. The examples I referred where all single dimension.

Comment: You have asked 10 questions and have **never** accepted any answer. Did you not get any right answer for your questions?
And for this one _what have you tried so far?_

Comment: no it is not like that i have not accepted answer.Even yesterday i asked and got answer and checked.For this one i tried  in this way.

Comment: @names = grep {my $name = $$_[0]; not grep $_ eq $name, @employees} @names; but how to access coloumn field i did not know.

Answer (score 4):

You can build `%seen` hash lookup and filter `@$array2`,

```
my %seen;
@seen{ map $_->{id}, @$array1 } = ();

@$array2 = grep { !exists $seen{$_->{id}} } @$array2;
```

Comment: sorry i did not got result exactly.

Comment: @user762641 https://eval.in/379687